# /dev/mapper Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary

Tags: linux, lvm, partition

How to fix "Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary" for "Disk /dev/mapper/isw_ddfdcbhjcj_Volume0"?

```
sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_ddfdcbhjcj_Volume0: 935.4 GiB, 1004400541696 bytes, 1961719808 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device                                   Boot Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/mapper/isw_ddfdcbhjcj_Volume0-part1          1 4294967295 4294967295   2T ee GPT

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use tools that don't understand GPT partitioned devices, on GPT partitioned devices.

Comment: So what tools should I use?

Comment: parted, gdisk, a less ancient version of fdisk?

Comment: I have tried parted, but it report an error "Invalid argument during seek for read on  /dev/mapper/isw_ddfdcbhjcj_Volume0". I chose Ignore, and another error "The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used." was reported.   gdisk said "invalid backup GPT header, but valid main header; regenerating backup header from main header."......